# tizen:app-control in Gear S

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk

The rich Notification documentation tell us we can do something like this:

SrnImageAsset checkInIcon = new SrnImageAsset(context, "checkin_icon", checkInIconBitmap);
myAction.setIcon(checkInIcon);
myAction.setPackage("com.mypackage.myapp");
myAction.setData(Uri.parse("checkin://venue_id=12345"));

It means we can open a custom app with a custom app-control.

But i don't know how to make it work. I don't even know which package I have to set. "com.mypackage.myapp" seems to be the android package because the tizen one has a different format.

---

What I do:

**Config.xml:**

```
    <tizen:app-control>
        <tizen:operation name="http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/view"/>
        <tizen:src name="index.html"/>
        <tizen:uri name="myapp"/>
    </tizen:app-control>

</widget>
```

**Java:**

```
myAction.setPackage("L1NG56dhCi");
myAction.setData(Uri.parse("myapp://newsId=1"));
```

When I click on the action icon in the notification of the Gear, I see in the log (without more interesting info):
[app_control_send_launch_request]LAUNCH_REJECTED(0xc0000000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found it!
The secret is to never call setPackage(), only this:

```
SrnRemoteLaunchAction myAction = new SrnRemoteLaunchAction("Open the news");
Bitmap checkInIconBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),  R.drawable.ic_notif);
myAction.setIcon( new SrnImageAsset(context, "checkin_icon", checkInIconBitmap));

myAction.setData(Uri.parse("myapp://test"));
myAction.setOperation("http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/view");
myRichNotification.addAction(myAction);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set myAction.setPackage to the stock version before trying to make customization. This is a mandatory requirement from Samsung due to the fact Tizen is based of an ARM processor rather than a Dalvik one.